# Pandas: How to look at the shape of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to process raw data `data_mrna_agilent_microarray_zscores_ref_all_samples.txt` and look at the shape of the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

dir = "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Cancer_Pathways/gbm_tcga/"

class DataProcessing:

    def __init__(self, data, header=0):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\t",header = header)

    def split_data(self):
        X = self.df.iloc[:, :-1]
        y = self.df.iloc[:, -1]
        return X, y

    def kegg_genes(self):
        # do something
        self

    def pathways(self):
        # do something
        self

    def pca(self):
        pca = PCA()
        if np.any(np.isnan(self.df)):
            pass
        elif np.all(np.isfinite(self.df)):
            pass
        else:
            pca.fit(self.df.iloc[1:, 3:])
            self.pca_components = pca.components_
            return self.pca_components

rna = DataProcessing(dir + "data_mrna_agilent_microarray_zscores_ref_all_samples.txt")
rna.shape
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-ee837472fd17> in <module>()
     33 
     34 rna = DataProcessing(dir + "data_mrna_agilent_microarray_zscores_ref_all_samples.txt")
---> 35 rna.shape

AttributeError: 'DataProcessing' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: You could add a `@property` called `shape` to the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

More of a python question than of a pandas question. Dataframes indeed have a property called shape but again, it is the dataframes that have that property, not your own custom class. The dataframe here is in `rna.df`which means to get the shape of that you need to access the df instead. `rna.df.shape`